# What cluster management software does there exist for Windows, except for MS HPC Server?

Tags: windows, cluster, hpc

Do there exist any open-source solutions? Perhaps, cheaper commercial ones?

I'm surprised that googling does not yield anything meaningful for me.

Comment: What do you mean by cluster management software?  Normal windows clusters can be managed by the built in management tools just fine.  Is there a feature you think is lacking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah - no. Windows HPC allows you to use the very cheap WIndows HPC edition licenses. If you take naother management - and need windows - it is back to standard edition windows, which costs a LOT more than the node cost of HPC cluster. The result of a zero costs solution would thus be still MORE expensive than the MS HPC cost. That is, if you really need a HPC cluster and was not mixing that up with MS "standard" clustering, in which case, though, teh same logic applies - management services cost zero and are included in the actual licenses.

Comment: But if he's talking about MS Cluster Service (the non-HPC clustering for failover), then why would he be seeking a 3rd-party provider for it? Doesn't make sense, it would be like looking for a different VSS provider for NTFS. Even if a 3rd-party could write one, they'd be unlikely to be able to or want to.

Comment: It also makes no sense for HPC clusters as he looses the REALLY low licensing costs for the Windows HPC version. As I said - this makes no sense regardless which direction you look at it from.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that the HPC edition costed much less than the standard edition.